# Shiro blocking CORS requests with HTTP 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: angular, dropwizard, shiro

I am facing an issue where in shiro blocks cross origin requests stating the below error. If I take out Shiro and my requests are going through fine and I am able to get a successful response back.

> My dropwizard application is hosted on 
>   http://localhost:8199/api/konak/orders and my angular application is
>   being launched from http://localhost:4200

**Error**

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin. 401 Unauthorized error

I have started by angular application by passing in the proxy file, `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`. I am running my angular application with the below proxy details

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8199",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Below is my Request-Response headers

**General**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8199/api/konak/reconciliations
Request Method:GET
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Remote Address:[::1]:8199
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Request Headers**

```
Content-Length:0
Date:Wed, 02 Aug 2017 13:17:49 GMT
WWW-Authenticate:BASIC realm="application"
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8199
Origin:http://localhost:4200
Referer:http://localhost:4200/konak-dashboard
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36
```

I have also setup Shiro authentication and I suspect Shiro is causing some issue and not able to accept the request. (I have masked the ladap details and jndildaprealm details, but they work fine)

**shiro.ini file**

```
l# Use SSO
contextFactory = org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapContextFactory
contextFactory.url = ldap://<hidden-ldap-config>
contextFactory.systemUsername = svc-gitlab
contextFactory.systemPassword = xxxxxxxxxxxx

ldapRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapRealm
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate = {0}<@company.domain>
ldapRealm.contextFactory = $contextFactory
    allowAllCredentialsMatcher=org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.AllowAllCredentialsMatcher

authenticationStrategy = org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.AllSuccessfulStrategy
securityManager.authenticator.authenticationStrategy = $authenticationStrategy

waffleRealmSSO = waffle.shiro.negotiate.NegotiateAuthenticationRealm
waffleUserPass = waffle.shiro.GroupMappingWaffleRealm
waffleFilter = waffle.shiro.negotiate.NegotiateAuthenticationFilter

securityManager.realms= $waffleRealmSSO, $ldapRealm

# Use the configured native session manager:
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
# the following call is only necessary in a web-configured ShiroFilter (otherwise
# a native session manager is already enabled):
securityManager.sessionMode = native

# cookie for single sign on
cookie = org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie
cookie.name = SSOcookie
cookie.path = /
securityManager.sessionManager.sessionIdCookie = $cookie

authcStrategy = waffle.shiro.negotiate.NegotiateAuthenticationStrategy
securityManager.authenticator.authenticationStrategy = $authcStrategy

[urls]
/** = port[8199], authcBasic, noSessionCreation
```

I have added my CORS headers to my Dropwizard Application as follows

```
 private void enableCorsHeaders(Environment env) {
        final FilterRegistration.Dynamic corsFilter = env.servlets().addFilter("CrossOriginFilter", CrossOriginFilter.class);

        corsFilter.setInitParameter("Access-Header", "true");
        corsFilter.setInitParameter("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        corsFilter.setInitParameter("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        corsFilter.setInitParameter("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Cache-Control, Pragma, Expires");
        corsFilter.setInitParameter("Access-Control-Allow-Methods\" ", "OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,HEAD");
        corsFilter.setInitParameter("allowedOrigins", "*");
        corsFilter.setInitParameter("allowedHeaders", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin");
        corsFilter.setInitParameter("allowedMethods", "OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,HEAD");
        corsFilter.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.CHAIN_PREFLIGHT_PARAM, Boolean.FALSE.toString());

        // Add URL mapping
        corsFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), true, "/*");
    }
```